# read windows build version from image

Tags: windows-10, deployment, version

i am trying to read the windows build version (21H1,20H2 ...) from an installation iso file.

Until some time ago I used the workflow of mounting the corresponding .iso, asking the \source\setup.exe for its file version and then matching it with https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information .

But since Windows 2004 I have the problem that these versions differ from each other. For example I have a .iso for a Windows 10 **21H1** - which should have a build version around 10.0.**19043**.xxx according to the website, but the setup.exe inside the .iso has the version 10.0.**19041**.xxx.

So I've tryied to use dism to check the build verion (dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:E:\sources\install.wim /index:1) but I also get the information "Version: 10.0.**19041**".

According to the website this is not correct for the 21H1.

After an installation on a VM for test purposes, the winver shows me as expected the version 21H1(Build **10943**.929)

Technicaly, this make sense to me because the setup contains the same base "setup" and probably there are some ServicePacks that are installed after the base version (**10941**.xxx)

So, its not possible to resolve that problem via service pack number because these numbers are not in an logical order (20H2 updated Nov 2021 has a later service pack number than 21H1 updated Oct 2021)

Comment: Service Packs do not exist for Windows 8+.

Comment: if i ask dism for the wiminfo, i'll get an service pack build, service pack number...